# How to add relevant scale bars on inset maps using tmap

Tags: viewport, tmap

[image]I used tmap to create the plot attached. However, I would like to add a scale bar to the inset map, but I haven't been able to figured out how to do that. Can someone please help me?

Here are the codes that I used to create the attached map:

```
 main_map <- tmap::tm_shape(main_map_df) +
  tmap::tm_polygons(
    col = "var.q5",
    palette = c("#CCCCCC", "#999999", "#666666", "#333333", "#000000"),
    #alpha = 0.7,
    lwd = 0.5,
    title = "") +
  tmap::tm_layout(
    frame = FALSE,
    legend.outside = TRUE,
    legend.hist.width = 5,
    legend.text.size = 0.5,
    fontfamily = "Verdana") +
  tmap::tm_scale_bar(
    position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"),
    breaks = c(0, 10, 20),
    text.size = 0.5
    ) +
  tmap::tm_compass(position = c("LEFT", "TOP")) 

inset_map <- tmap::tm_shape(inset_map_df) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(main_map_df) +
  tm_fill("grey50") +
  tmap::tm_scale_bar(
    position = c("LEFT", "BOTTOM"),
    breaks = c(0, 10, 20),
    text.size = 0.5
  )

# Combine crude rate map (inset + main) =====

tiff(
  "main_map_w_iset.tiff",
  height = 1200,
  width = 1100,
  compression = "lzw",
  res = 300
  )
main_map
print(
  inset_map,
  vp = viewport(
    x = 0.7, 
    y = 0.18, 
    width = 0.3, 
    height = 0.3,
    clip = "off")
  )
dev.off()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using the World data set:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(grid)
data("World")

# main map
tm_main <- World %>% 
  filter(name == "Australia") %>% 
  tm_shape() +
  tm_polygons(col = "red", 
              alpha = .5) +
  tm_scale_bar()

# inset map
tm_inset <- tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons(col = "gray", 
              alpha = .5) +
  tm_scale_bar()

vp <- viewport(x = .615, y = .5, width = .6, height = .6, just = c("right", "top"))

# final map
tmap_save(tm_main, filename = "test_inset.png", insets_tm = tm_inset, insets_vp = vp,
          height = 200, width = 200, units = "mm")
```

[image]